# Pytorch MSE loss function nan during training

Tags: python, pytorch

I am trying linear regression from boston dataset. MSE loss function is nan since the first iteration. I tried altering learning rate and batch_size but of no use.

```
from torch.utils.data import TensorDataset , DataLoader
inputs  = torch.from_numpy(Features).to(torch.float32)
targets = torch.from_numpy(target).to(torch.float32)
train_ds = TensorDataset(inputs , targets)
train_dl = DataLoader(train_ds , batch_size = 5 , shuffle = True)
```

```
model = nn.Linear(13,1)
opt = optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=1e-5)
loss_fn = F.mse_loss
```

```
def fit(num_epochs, model, loss_fn, opt, train_dl):
    
    # Repeat for given number of epochs
    for epoch in range(num_epochs):
        
        # Train with batches of data
        for xb,yb in train_dl:
            
            # 1. Generate predictions
            pred = model(xb)
            
            # 2. Calculate loss
            loss = loss_fn(pred, yb)
            
            # 3. Compute gradients
            loss.backward()
            
            # 4. Update parameters using gradients
            opt.step()
            
            
            # 5. Reset the gradients to zero
            opt.zero_grad()
        
        # Print the progress
        if (epoch+1) % 10 == 0:
            print('Epoch [{}/{}], Loss: {}'.format(epoch+1, num_epochs, loss.item()))


fit(100, model, loss_fn , opt , train_dl)
```

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0n3I.png)

Comment: In the first glance, it seem to be a problem with the dataset (ie Features) or model initialization. To be certain of that, set the learning rate to 0 or print the model's prediction at every step. I suppose the predictions are nan and hence the loss becomes nan (not the other way round).

Comment: First, use nn.MSELoss instead of F.mse_loss (but I dont think that will make the difference). Second, print the loss every epoch instead of every 10th, maybe at the beginning the loss is a number. Also print the predictions, thats more important. And because we dont know what your data is, further help is difficult to provide

Answer (score 2):

Pay attention to:

1. Use normalization: `x = (x - x.mean()) / x.std()`
2. `y_train / y_test` have to be (-1, 1) shapes. Use `y_train.view(-1, 1)` (if y_train is torch.Tensor or something)
3. (not your case, but for someone else) If you use `torch.nn.MSELoss(reduction='sum')` than you have to reduse the sum to mean. It can be done with torch.nn.MSELoss() or in train-loop: `l = loss(y_pred, y) / y.shape[0]`.

Example:

```py
    ...
    loss = torch.nn.MSELoss()  
    ...
    for epoch in range(num_epochs):  
        for x, y in train_iter:  
            y_pred = model(x)  
            l = loss(y_pred, y)  
            optimizer.zero_grad()  
            l.backward()  
            optimizer.step()  
        print("epoch {} loss: {:.4f}".format(epoch + 1, l.item()))
```